# Why does gzip use CRC instead of a general hash algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash, gzip, digital-signature, crc

What is the difference between a [Digital Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) and a [codeword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Application)?

**CONTEXT:**
I've been having to do a decent amount of work with gzipped files recently. [One interesting thing I found while reading the Python zlib documentation is the claim that CRC should not be used as a general hash algorithm.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) This made me wonder, what's the point of a CRC if it's not a general hash algorithm? Isn't the point to check equality?

Comment: Some algorithms have a better avalanche than others (fewer collisions) over a broad range of input.  I have heard that mentioned as a reason.

Comment: Just general error mitigation I though

Comment: One thing to consider: Generic hash algorithms where not so widely available and understood when GZIP was defined. Also, computing CRC is significantly faster and requires only one register.

Comment: GZIP was created to run on machines with memory measured in KB and speeds in MHz. Them fancy-pants hash functions were for academics and people with big iron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CRC in zip files is mainly used to make sure that the file is not damaged during storage or transit. It is not used to provide authenticity or protect against files being changed by an attacker. So the cryptographic safety is not required.

Cryptographic hashes do provide the same or better protection against integrity failures. They are however more computational intensive and they require a larger output. If the output of the hash is reduced too much then CRC may actually provide better detection of (random) changes.

As the CRC value does not protect against deliberate changes - it isn't difficult to find files that would generate the same CRC value - it is not suitable for digital signatures. For that you *do* need a cryptographic hash.

Note that a cryptographic hash is not a signature. For signatures you need a digital signature application such as PGP. Digital signatures (generally) consist of a hash that is then processed using information from a private key (verified by the public key at the receiver).

---

Note: sometimes the word "signature" to mean "fingerprint". For fingerprints a cryptographic hash - mostly MD5 or SHA-1 *is* still used. But that's a rather far fetched and - in my opinion - incorrect use of the word "signature".

Answer (score 5):

You asked four or five different questions there and use a whole bunch of different, sometimes ambiguous terms in the context.  It is better to ask one clear question at a time on a question and answer site.

1. Why does gzip use CRC instead of a general hash algorithm?

A CRC is good at error detection and is relatively fast to compute.  The input bits are well distributed in the CRC, and it also has good burst error detection capability.  That is why.  It is not clear what you mean by "general hash algorithm" (just for hash tables? or cryptographically strong?).  In any case, the purpose is not to make a lookup table of files, nor is it to sign the data.  There would be no value anyway in putting a cryptographic hash, e.g. MD5 or SHA-2, in the gzip file, since someone could simply change the data *and* the hash!  A hash that anyone can generate is only useful if you get the hash over a different channel.

2. What is the difference between a Digital Signature and a codeword?

By "codeword", I presume from the link you mean a CRC.  A CRC is a quickly computed error check code, implemented in both hardware and software applications to check the integrity of the data.  From the context, I think you mean cryptographic hash when you say digital signature.  A cryptographic hash is a one-way function that is designed to make it extremely difficult to create a message with a given hash value.  CRCs are the exact opposite.  Being a linear function, it is quite easy to [modify a message to have any given CRC](http://zlib.net/spoof.c.gz).  A cryptographic hash usually has many more bits than a CRC in order to make the probability of an accidental collision effectively impossible.  However the one-way and many bits make the cryptographic hash much more computationally intensive to generate.

3. One interesting thing I found while reading the Python zlib documentation is the claim that CRC should not be used as a general hash algorithm.

That is correct.  While a CRC distributes the input bits very well into the value and can be used successfully as a hash, [it fails certain tests that you might like a hash algorithm to pass](http://bretmulvey.com/hash/8.html).  If you want an algorithm to make a hash table from keys, then use a [hash algorithm designed for that purpose](https://code.google.com/p/cityhash/).  If that's all it's for, the hash need not and should not be cryptographic.  Fast is more important.

4. what's the point of a CRC if it's not a general hash algorithm?

A CRC is one result of [coding theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory), which provides algorithms for error detection and correction.  The purpose of a CRC is error detection.

5. Isn't the point to check equality?

It is not clear what equality you are referring to here.  In any case, the point of the CRC is to check *integrity*.  It provides redundant information in a stream that will detect almost any inadvertent corruption of that stream in transit.

Comment: It's a fair point that I asked many different questions. I mainly asked this question because of all the jargon soup I was given in my documentation reading. Now that you've laid things out neatly I can see the multiple questions but in my mind it was a single question with context when I wrote this.

Comment: I didn't specify what a "general hash function" is because the python documentation that I linked didn't. As such I was hoping this question would clear that up.

Comment: Also, thank you for all the additional reading material. Especially  the Spoof.c example.